# Homestead in a Ubuntu 14 VBox - Setup Errors

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, virtualbox, homestead

I am having some issues setting up my dev environment.
My setup:

- Windows 10 Host
- Running Ubuntu 14 in a VirtualBox instance
- Install Homestead
- vagrant up
- This [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qb8t.png)

> There was an error while executing VboxManage, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling Virtualbox. The command and stderr is shown below.
> Command: [hostonlyif", "create"]
> Stderr: 0%...
> Progress State: NS_ERROR_FAILURE VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter VboxManage: error: VboxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for > devboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
> VboxManage error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
> VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

I would greatly appreciate any insight into this issue, as my google-fu has failed me on this one (and some errors with dependencies concerning the right version of virtual box -- 5.1 doesn't work here, had to uninstall and downgrade to 5-- have depleted my energies).

Is it possible that this is an "inception" kind of issue regarding the fact that I'm setting up a virtual machine inside a virtual machine?

- The (first) VBox Storage settings: 50GB partitioned, 14 current size
- Granted the machine 1 cpu
- The network settings is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gbM6.png)

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem updating from Windows 7 to Windows 10.
You can see the solution in [my blog](http://www.jesusamieiro.com/problemas-con-vagrant-al-actualizar-windows-7-a-windows-10/) (in Spanish) and [automatically translated](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jesusamieiro.com%2Fproblemas-con-vagrant-al-actualizar-windows-7-a-windows-10%2F&edit-text=&act=url) with Google translator. It is not spam ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade linux kernel version. Its most probably about your hardware and linux kernel mismatch problem. Also Its not normal situation why are you using virtual machine inside virtual machine?.